# Accessing two MPU-9250 DMP

Tags: arduino-uno, accelerometer, mpu6050, gyroscope

I want to use both IMU at the same time using the [Sparkfun Library](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_MPU-9250-DMP_Arduino_Library) on a SAMD21 mini breakout board. Can anyone help?

The begin function is :

```
inv_error_t MPU9250_DMP::begin(void) {
  inv_error_t result;
  struct int_param_s int_param;
  Wire.begin();
  result = mpu_init(&int_param);
  if (result)
    return result;
  mpu_set_bypass(1); // Place all slaves (including compass) on primary bus
  setSensors(INV_XYZ_GYRO | INV_XYZ_ACCEL | INV_XYZ_COMPASS);
  _gSense = getGyroSens();
  _aSense = getAccelSens();
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to do it?

Comment: yes i tried but when connecting them togher i got the same data for both,actually i'm trying to modify the library to have to imu with two adresse 0x68 and 0x69

Comment: I have the same problem now. the function is burried in 3rd lvl of libraries..
Where did you change the code?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I'm not 100% sure of what you are trying to do, I don't understand 'both imu the' in your question.  I think you are trying to use two identical boards at the same time.  (If not tell me so I can edit my answer)

You will need to modify the library so the `begin` function takes a parameter.
That parameter for `MPU9250_DMP::begin` then identifies the address of the device, this will need passing to `Wire.begin()` I think (you'll need to check the Wire.begin() function, I can't).

That should let you create two different instances of the class.

```
MPU9250_DMP apple;
MPU9250_DMP banana;
apple.begin(0x68);
banana.begin(0x69);
```

Comment: yes i want to use this but in the begin function there is no parameter to pass

Comment: Erm, whoops, I missed a line out of the answer.  You need to change the library so `begin()` takes a parameter.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: thank you, i'm trying to modify it, now i'll test it and i'll give you the response

Comment: i changed the library,the problem is there is no data displayed ,when debugging even when i Print Something in the serial nothing displayed